# Active Directory - Enforce extra authentication

Tags: xml, active-directory, system, xacml

Is it possible to enforce extra authentication (via an external service) or an extra layer of decision making after a successful active directory authentication?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

You probably mean extra authorization given the tags you used (XACML). You would typically use AD / LDAP for authentication with an app. Once you retrieve the user's roles and groups, you can then call a Policy Decision Point (PDP) either from an interceptor or the application requesting authentication. The PDP would then authorize the request using XACML policies.

Comment: Yet this is exactly what I mean, giving an authentication verdict after a successful authentication. I will be very happy if you could supply a reference I can learn how to do it from.

Comment: Have a look at what Axiomatics does (disclaimer: this is where I work)